# How to modify a matrix to be positive semidefinite with as little pertubration as possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-distributions

I am experimenting with some small Gaussian processes experiments and I need to end up with a positive semidefinite covariance matrix. I am relatively sure I have done everything correctly but the resulting kernel is not positive semidefinite.

I have tried adding a jitter to the diagonal, $\Sigma + diag(\epsilon)$ but it still doesn't work. Is there something else I can do to ensure that the kernel will be positive semidefinite?

Comment: please describe how you generate the matrices

Comment: If adding $\epsilon$ to the diagonal doesn't work, that means your matrix is far from being pd, so there must be something wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: If you add $\epsilon$ to **every** diagonal entry of the matrix, then the result is necessarily positive definite.

Comment: If the size of your covariance matrix is $n$ and its rank is $r$, then you must perturb at least $n-r$ diagonal entries to produce a matrix of full rank

Comment: Actually there is something bizarre here: **every** covariance matrix is positive semidefinite. How are you ending up with a matrix that is not positive semidefinite?

Comment: hmm I guess I must have some problem with my covariance then, I will look into it